# how to install bootstrap-select on server

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use the select drop down [created here](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select) but I could use a little guidance as to how to go about installing it.

I'm assuming I copy over the CSS and js file into my own CSS and js folders, but do I also copy in the JavaScript line it mentions, or is that optional? I tried throwing it in between some script tags in my header, but that didn't get my select-box working.

For test purposes I'm using:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This demo page seems to have it all going on. Just copy from the set-up there: http://silviomoreto.github.com/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply include the .js and .css in your HTML can call `$('select').selectpicker();` to initialize the selectpicker. This will modify all the `select` tags on your page thought, if you want to modify only one, just change the selector.

I did a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hh4KP/ but the documentation and examples here: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ are pretty thorough.

Comment: The `$(document).ready(function(){` part was what wasn't occurring to me.  Thank you @Sashenka.